Number of paths through square-ish grid
I'm wondering what the number of paths through a square grid $a$ are, which has had a triangle removed off of its edge. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the number of squares left is 2, but I'm curious about the more general case.
A helpful illustration for $a=10$ and the case of 2 squares being left:
I know the number of paths through the grid that don't intersect the diagonal at all are given by the Catalan numbers, so a lower bound is $\frac{(2a)!}{(a+1)!a!}$, and an upper bound is of course the total number of paths through the full square $\frac{(2a)!}{a!^2}$. I've tried coming up with an expression for the number of paths that do cross this moved diagonal, my initial idea was just looking at the number of paths that cross the diagonal from $(0,2)$ to $(a-2,a)$, which I could get by just subtracting the $(a-2)$nd Catalan number from the total paths in the smaller square, but that leaves out paths that don't start at $(0,2)$.

You should clarify that each step is one unit right or one unit up.

This is answered in the Theorem 10.3.3. of this paper: Lattice Path Enumeration by
Christian Krattenthaler. The paper uses the notation: paths from $(a,b)$ to $(c,d)$ staying between the lines (lower) $y=x+s$ and (upper) $y=x+t$, so let's use $n$ as out parameter: $(a,b)=(0,0)$ and $(c,d)=(n,n)$. For the lower line, let's pick $s=-n$ so it will have no effect. In the upper line we keep the parameter $t$ (in the example $t=2$). The formula in the paper yields
$$
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \binom{2n}{n-k(t+n+2)} - \binom{2n}{n-k(t+n+2)+t+1}
$$
and the summand is nonzero only for the value $k=0$, so the answer is
$$
\binom{2n}{n} - \binom{2n}{n+t+1}.
$$
